# CSS set as display inline, but inspector showing block

Tags: css

I'm trying to set an `h3` tag to be inline, but no matter what rule I use in CSS, the box model in Inspector is displaying `display: block`.

[image]

```
.widget_title {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Any ideas to why this is?

Comment: That is the default style for h3 provided by browser. Can you create a sample demo of your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Don't use float in `inline` or `inline-block` displayed elements. Float convert it to `block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks simple: you use `float` property on inline element which forces `inline` element to become a `block` element.

[Read this CSS specs to learn more.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position)

Essential part is here:

> left 
>   The element generates a block box that is floated to the left.
>   Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top
>   (subject to the 'clear' property).

Comment: That's interesting, and absolutely correct. Removing the float, fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you use float, position absolute or fixed on an element you force this element **out of the normal flow**. When an element is out of the normal flow,  display: inline or inline-block for that matter, do not make any sense. This is why elements out of the normal flow are considered as block elements, whatever their display css property is.
[This](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) is an old but interesting article about floats.